# Why doesn't Chromium render a web page on one particular computer?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I have a strange problem using DCEF3 (last version - c30150c47432 - CEF 3.1650.1562) in a Delphi application.
All seems to be ok on all PC where I install application, except for a PC, where there is the following problem:
when Chromium loads web page with following code:

```
procedure TMainForm.StartNavigate();
var
  navigateto: String;

begin
  navigateto := 'http://' + URL;

  crm.Load(navigateto);

  crm.Repaint();
end;
```

the page is not rendered, Chromium's window remains blank.

This situation occurs on a particular PC with video card amd radeon hd 7650m and amd catalyst driver (may be this is relevant ?), on all other systems it's all ok.

Some suggestion ?

Comment: Where is your page coming from? Have you verified the correct page has been loaded?

Comment: Does it load on regular chromium?

Comment: Yes, on regular chromium it load correctly. On other PCs, in DCEF too ...